# \u0022 instead of " " with JsonResponse symfony

Tags: symfony

my problem is :
The data returned have \u0022 instead of "".

```
$em=$this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
$result = $em->getRepository('HomeBundle:Product')->findAll();

$encoders = array(new XmlEncoder(), new JsonEncoder());
$normalizers = array(new ObjectNormalizer());
$serializer = new Serializer($normalizers, $encoders);

$jsonContent = $serializer->serialize($result,'json');

$response = new JsonResponse($jsonContent);
$response->headers->set('Content-Type', 'application/json');
return $response;
```

and that's what i get

```
"[{\u0022id\u0022:1,\u0022name\u0022:\u0022opp\u0022,\u0022price\u0022:3},{\u0022id\u0022:2,\u0022name\u0022:\u0022opp\u0022,\u0022price\u0022:5},{\u0022id\u0022:3,\u0022name\u0022:\u0022oppv\u0022,\u0022price\u0022:16},{\u0022id\u0022:4,\u0022name\u0022:\u0022opp\u0022,\u0022price\u0022:6},{\u0022id\u0022:5,\u0022name\u0022:\u0022opp\u0022,\u0022price\u0022:7},{\u0022id\u0022:6,\u0022name\u0022:\u0022opp\u0022,\u0022price\u0022:34},{\u0022id\u0022:7,\u0022name\u0022:\u0022opp\u0022,\u0022price\u0022:56},{\u0022id\u0022:8,\u0022name\u0022:\u0022opp\u0022,\u0022price\u0022:30}]"
```

thanks in advance for your help

Answer (score 11, accepted):

As your entities are already serialised, change your `JsonResponse` to a `Response` :

```
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;

// ...
$response = new Response($jsonContent);
$response->headers->set('Content-Type', 'application/json');

return $response;
```

Or decode your results before create your `JsonResponse` :

```
return new JsonResponse(json_decode($jsonContent));
```

Note that the `Content-Type` of a `JsonResponse` is automatically `application/json`, no need to set it.