# Deserializing JSON response in Symfony

Tags: php, symfony4

In my API I have the following code:

```
$encoders = [new JsonEncoder()];
        $normalizer = new ObjectNormalizer();
        $normalizer->setIgnoredAttributes(array('company','profile','createdAt','profileName','appui','id','brokerId','productList','appkey'));

        $serializer = new Serializer([$normalizer], $encoders);

        return new JsonResponse($serializer->serialize($products, 'json'),
        JsonResponse::HTTP_OK
        );
```

It returned the following:

```
"[{\u0022name\u0022:\u0022i2\u0022,\u0022serial\u0022:\u0022i2\u0022,\u0022sgin\u0022:\u00225d134d280f1a9\u0022},{\u0022name\u0022:\u0022i3\u0022,\u0022serial\u0022:\u0022i3\u0022,\u0022sgin\u0022:\u00225d134dbb1609f\u0022},{\u0022name\u0022:\u0022i4\u0022,\u0022serial\u0022:\u0022i4\u0022,\u0022sgin\u0022:\u00225d1351c3c0153\u0022},{\u0022name\u0022:\u0022i5\u0022,\u0022serial\u0022:\u0022i5\u0022,\u0022sgin\u0022:\u00225d13520472ab8\u0022},{\u0022name\u0022:\u0022i6\u0022,\u0022serial\u0022:\u0022i6\u0022,\u0022sgin\u0022:\u00225d13526e4cdbc\u0022}]"
```

But when I try to use it in another site, I don't get it properly deserialized. It just returned that string rather than a JSON object.

Comment: I would assume that `$serializer->serialize` is returning a string, which is then being encoded to work as JSON.  I think you need to pass a data structure in here and not a string (Don't know what that means in your code, but usually it would be a case of passing `$products` in instead)

Answer (score 0):

[send the value through json_decode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35973179/u0022-instead-of-with-jsonresponse-symfony)

I found a response here after realizing what you said about it being sent as string. It was clearly unicode. So, the suggestion on that page is use json_decode inside JsonReponse first. And it worked.